# Passing JSP encrypted parameters to a servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I want to pass encrypted parameters via a JSP form to frmservlet.I want to pass `userid` by encrypting it.But it is not decrypt by the `frmsrvlet`,How can I do this?

Comment: And "frmservlet" is what, exactly?

Comment: frmservlet mean servlet integrated with oracle forms

Answer (score 1):

Serve your page over HTTPS, and have

```
<form action="https://yoursite/yourctx/yourServlet">
```

You'd have to [enable SSL/TLS](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html) on your server.